Extruded aluminium profile - Connector question
So I've been using 2020 aluminium profile to build a box I've been using these corner connectors:
https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/my8xc58nnn4.png
They are great, but now I've got the problem where I'm trying to make a lid for this box and the dimensions are a little off.
I was hoping I could find a similar corner connector but TWO WAY instead of THREE WAY.
A quick look and I've found this type of corner piece:
https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/pyq9clnzev4.png
Main issue with it is I don't want to have to tap the 'inner core?' of the aluminium profile to fit it. Are there any alternatives or am I better off angle grinding the 3 way corners?

This seems like a shopping question "where do I get 2 way connectors"...

I'm not sure you can even get them, it's why I'm asking

Angle grinder or rotary with a cutter and a good set of cobalt drill bits. Alternatively, a sheet metal route exists with shears and thin sheet metal.
